# Calcul new coords of camera after a 90 degres rotation in a isometric 2D projection

Tags: xna, camera, rendering, game-engine, isometric

I made a 2D isometric renderer. It works fine but now I want to show my scene from 4 differents point of view (NO NW SE SW) but, **on a 90° rotation, my camera cannot keep the center of my scene on screen.**

*What's working :*

- I calcul new projection of scene to match the new viewport (x y z in my world).
- I reorganise part of my scene(chunk) to draw them in a correct order
- I reorganise 'tiles' of 'chunks' to draw them in a correct order
- I can keep the correct center with a 180 degres rotation.

*What's do not working :*

- I cannot find a correct translation to apply to my camera after a 90 degres rotation.

*What I know :*

- To keep the same center on a 180° rotation with my camera I have to do this :

`camera.Position -= new Vector2(2 * camera.Position.X + camera.Width, 2 * camera.Position.Y + camera.Height);`

**Illustration**
[image: sceen from SE point of view]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the center of your map is origo (0,0,0), this gets easy:

First you store your default camera position in a Vector3 CameraOffset, then you calculate position using a rotation-matrix. 90* in redians is half a Pi, so we will use PiOverTwo. We will also use an enum to decide what direction to be pointing, so you can say

Camera.Orientation = Orientation.East;

and the camera should fix itself :)

```
public enum Orientation
{
    North, East, South, West
}
```

in camera:

```
public Vector3 Position { get; protected set; }

Vector3 _CameraOffset = new Vector3(0, 20, 20);
public Vector3 CameraOffset
{
    get
    {
        return _Orientation;
    }

    set
    {
        _Orientation = value;
        UpdateOrientation();
    }
}

Orientation _Orientation = Orientation.North;
public Orientation Orientation
{
    get
    {
        return _Orientation;
    }

    set
    {
        _Orientation = value;
        UpdateOrientation();
    }
}

private void UpdateOrientation()
{
    Position = Vector3.Transform(CameraOffset, Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOverTwo * (int)Orientation));
}
```

If you want a gliding movement between positions, I think I can help too ;)

If your camera does not focus on Vector3.Zero and should not rotate around it, you just need to change:

```
Position = Vector3.Transform(CameraOffset, Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOverTwo * (int)Orientation));
```

to:

```
Position = Vector3.Transform(CameraOffset, Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.PiOverTwo * (int)Orientation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(FocusPoint));
```

Here, FocusPoint is the point in 3D that you rotate around (your worlds center). And now you also know how to let your camera move around, if you call UpdateOrientation() in your Camera.Update() ;)

EDIT; So sorry, totally missed the point that you use 2D. I'll be back later to see if I can help :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will test this evening but It looks the good one. Indeed for my 180° rotation, make a translation of Pi is logic.

Comment: I got an idea, i'll try to make a 1,1 rotation, then reapply the isometric transformation.

Comment: I did correctly my rotation with 90°, Vector2(new_camera_x,new_camera_y) = new Vector2(-(old_camera_y - old_camera_height)/2,old_camera_x*2), or a kind of. It 's correct for a Z = 0 in my world but if I change altitude, all is wrong. So finally I need to find the center of my scene (X Y Z) and rotate arround it (par matrice ou simple decallage avant/apres).

Comment: I resolved my issue by calculating tile elligeable to be the center of the screen. Then, I pick up the nearest one of the camera and, after a rotation, I put it back to the middle of the screen. It's a quite easy like this but finally I have to calculate the tile in the center of my screen (because Z axis).